# Android emulator with no telephony support

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to figure out will my application work properly on a device with no telephony support (like most of modern tablets) and since I don't have any real device to test on I've tried to create an emulator instance and tell it something like `hw.telephony=no` but I failed. There are no such option in hardware preferences.

Is it possible to create such an emulator instance?

Maybe `hw.gsmModem=no` will act as no telephony support?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Emulator with GSM modem support = no.

**It is possible.**

If your application makes calls, you need to add this to the Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Beware as you will not have Internet access.. or at least I don't know how, as i'm trying to find out here: [How to access the internet with an Emulator simulating Android Tablet without GSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824352/simulate-android-tablet-without-gsm)